# Group permissions and sudoers file in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-12.04, sudo, sudoers

I have this folder "/var/www" under Ubuntu 12.04 and I want all the members of the group 'deploy' to be able to change it at will.

Then I need all users of this group to create folders and files that belong specifically to the user 'deployer'. Hence, the permissions would be like '775' all over, the owner would be always deployer and the group always deploy.

I am using 'sudo -u deployer' to execute all actions, but I want this group not to be prompted for password because one or other member should be allowed to run a batch script.

I've been trying to change the sudoers file, but nothing happens, any clue?

Last time I tried this line:

`%deploy ALL=(deployer) NOPASSWD: ALL`

I also tried:

`%deploy ALL=(deployer) sudoedit /var/www/*`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was quick.

It looks like the order of lines in the sudoers file is relevant. If the lines are in the top, it doesn't work. If they are below, it works. =P